# How to align 2 of the 3 link tags to the right?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
     <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td>
         <a id="btnAutoSuggest">Suggest Title</a>
         <a id="btnOK">OK</a>
         <a id="btnCancel">Cancel</a>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I would like the OK and Cancel buttons to be right aligned.  How can I accomplish that?  I setup a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/d6pDLtdkI87U0h9DJc7e?p=preview) to demonstrate the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `float`:

```
 #btnOK, #btnCancel {
   width: 90px;
   float:right;
}
```

Check **[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/KucF458Z86T691Z2i4pd?p=preview)**

You can also change the order in HTML to get first the *OK* button:

```
<td >
  <a id="btnAutoSuggest">Suggest Title</a>
  <a id="btnCancel">Cancel</a>
  <a id="btnOK">OK</a>
</td>
```

Check **[This](http://plnkr.co/edit/A5Hcmpj2xeTFITTyHXeb?p=preview)**

Comment: Dear downvoter please take the time to explain and then I can improve the answer .

Comment: @AngryHacker Np glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

For this exact scenario, I would do something like this.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
<td></td>
    <td >
        <a id="btnAutoSuggest">Suggest Title</a>
        <div class="align-right">
            <a id="btnOK">OK</a>
            <a id="btnCancel">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

**CSS**

```
<style>
    .align-right{
        float: right;
    }
</style>
```

The reason I've wrapped the buttons into a div is when you want to give some pagging or margin from sides or top/down, you will do it easily just by styling the div, so your controls move together.